# Wanting to extend Log::info

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

In the docs it says I can use Log::listen.

Below is my working code:

```
Log::listen(function($level, $message, $context)
{
$logFile = storage_path('logs/laravel.enriched.log');
$monolog = new Logger('log');
$monolog->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($logFile), Logger::INFO);
$monolog->info($message, Config::get('debug.extra_data'));
});
```

The file is required in the global.php file.  The problem I am facing is that when the `Log::info(‘example’)`, is called I get same information logged in 10 times instead of one.
Whilst I want one log per log that gets called.
(I am working with Laravel 4.2)